# Laravel Eloquent getting value from related table

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get all articles for the topic with comments and user's vote for the article if exists.

The schema is following:

```
article
id | topic | title | text

article_comments
article_id | comment_id

comments
id | text

votes
id | article_id | user_id
```

Comments are joined via Many to Many relationship.

The query I use now is

```
    $articles = Article::where('topic', $topic)
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(15);
```

What I need is to add something like this to the query:

```
v.value as 'v_value'...
LEFT JOIN votes v ON (v.article_id=a.id AND v.user_id = :user_id)
```

There is a possibility, that article won't have a vote from this user - in this case the row in votes table will be missing.

Could someone give me a hint

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Usually you want to use relation and then [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) `votes` like:

```
$articles = Article::where('topic', $topic)
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->with('votes')
            ->paginate(15);
```

Now, you'll have `votes` loaded in `$articles` collection too.